# How to enable kinds for C++ in universal ctags from the command line

Tags: ctags, universal-ctags

I cannot seem to toggle any of the C++ kinds for universal ctags on the command line.

How do I get all kinds that are not enabled to be enabled?

I have run:

```
> ctags -R --kinds-c++=ADLNUZcdefghlmnpstuvxz .*
```

In an attempt to enable all C++ kinds in universal ctags.

However when I check to see if they are enabled, I get:

```
> ctags --list-kinds-full=c++
#LETTER NAME       ENABLED REFONLY NROLES MASTER DESCRIPTION
A       alias      no      no      0      NONE   namespace aliases
D       macroparam no      no      0      C      parameters inside macro definitions
L       label      no      no      0      C      goto labels
N       name       no      no      0      NONE   names imported via using scope::symbol
U       using      no      no      0      NONE   using namespace statements
Z       tparam     no      no      0      NONE   template parameters
c       class      yes     no      0      NONE   classes
d       macro      yes     no      2      C      macro definitions
e       enumerator yes     no      0      C      enumerators (values inside an enumeration)
f       function   yes     no      0      C      function definitions
g       enum       yes     no      0      C      enumeration names
h       header     yes     yes     2      C      included header files
l       local      no      no      0      C      local variables
m       member     yes     no      0      C      class, struct, and union members
n       namespace  yes     no      0      NONE   namespaces
p       prototype  no      no      0      C      function prototypes
s       struct     yes     no      0      C      structure names
t       typedef    yes     no      0      C      typedefs
u       union      yes     no      0      C      union names
v       variable   yes     no      0      C      variable definitions
x       externvar  no      no      0      C      external and forward variable declarations
z       parameter  no      no      0      C      function parameters inside function or prototype definitions
```

My version of universal ctags is:

```
> ctags --version
Universal Ctags 6.0.0(p6.0.20230604.0), Copyright (C) 2015-2022 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jun  5 2023, 19:26:36
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Output version: 0.0
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +iconv, +option-directory, +packcc, +optscript
```

Answer (score 0):

An asterisk is for enabling all the kinds:

```
$ ctags --options=NONE --kinds-c++='*' --list-kinds-full=c++
ctags: Notice: No options will be read from files or environment
#LETTER NAME       ENABLED REFONLY NROLES MASTER DESCRIPTION
A       alias      yes     no      0      NONE   namespace aliases
D       macroparam yes     no      0      C      parameters inside macro definitions
L       label      yes     no      0      C      goto labels
N       name       yes     no      0      NONE   names imported via using scope::symbol
U       using      yes     no      0      NONE   using namespace statements
Z       tparam     yes     no      0      NONE   template parameters
c       class      yes     no      0      NONE   classes
d       macro      yes     no      2      C      macro definitions
e       enumerator yes     no      0      C      enumerators (values inside an enumeration)
f       function   yes     no      0      C      function definitions
g       enum       yes     no      0      C      enumeration names
h       header     yes     yes     2      C      included header files
l       local      yes     no      0      C      local variables
m       member     yes     no      0      C      class, struct, and union members
n       namespace  yes     no      0      NONE   namespaces
p       prototype  yes     no      0      C      function prototypes
s       struct     yes     no      0      C      structure names
t       typedef    yes     no      0      C      typedefs
u       union      yes     no      0      C      union names
v       variable   yes     no      0      C      variable definitions
x       externvar  yes     no      0      C      external and forward variable declarations
z       parameter  yes     no      0      C      function parameters inside function or prototype definitions
```

Comment: Didn't work, same output as before.